# Installing amazon.aws or community.aws collection through requirements.yml is not working

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

This is my requirements.yml file

```
---
collections:
- amazon.aws
- community.aws
```

and I run the command

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
```

The command runs and silently finishes. Is this right? Should it not tell whether it is installing these collections?

I am using ansible-2.9.17

Comment: I don't understand the idea behind this question; did the two requested collections not work after the command ran? Did you check the exit code `$?` and found it was inaccurate? What is the _problem_ you are trying to solve?

Comment: And to confirm what you think it does or think it does not, you can always run it with any flavour of `-v`, `-vv`, `-vvv` or `-vvvv` depending on the verbosity you'd like to see.

Comment: The command does not seem to install anything when these collections are put in the requirements.yml file. The question is essentially, whether my requirements file structure is correct or if the command invocation is erroneous. I am able to install collections individually using --  ansible-galaxy collection install amazon.aws --

Comment: Also adding verbosity just prints the ansible version statement and the location of ansible.cfg

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
community.amazon.aws
```

works like charm

Comment: did you mean amazon.aws?